# Pass the exception from my class to my form

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get my exception from my class to show as a windows error ?

This is my  class :

```
public class Editcap
{
    private string _newFileName;

    public void convertFileToLibpcap(string filePath)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        _newFileName = fileInfo.FullName.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, "_new") + ".pcap";
        invokeProcess(WiresharkProcesses.Editcap, string.Format("{2}{0}{2} -F libpcap {2}{1}{2}", fileInfo.FullName, _newFileName, "\""));
        deleteFile(filePath);
    }

    private void deleteFile(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public string getNewFileName()
    {
        return _newFileName;
    }
}
```

From my form:

The function creates new [wireshark](/questions/tagged/wireshark) file with different extension and should delete the old file. If it fails to delete, I want to show the message error in pop up window

```
Editcap editpcap = new Editcap();
editpcap.convertFileToLibpcap(file.FullName);
```

Comment: O_o **Do not** rethrow exceptions, that way. You're losing information. If you do nothing with _business relevance_ in the `catch` block, don't catch exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything, the exception will bubble up all on it's own; it's how they work.

Just add a `Try`/`Catch` around your calling code:

```
try
{
    Editcap editpcap = new Editcap();
    editpcap.convertFileToLibpcap(file.FullName);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error deleting the file.");
}
```

Note that there is no need (and in fact some harm) to catching and then re-throwing a new exception in your `deleteFile` method.  You're changing the type of the exception from the more specific and informative `IOException` to the less expressive `Exception`, and you're also taking out a lot of the stack trace information.  It would be better to just remove that try/catch entirely from `deleteFile`.  It also means you can change the calling code to catch `IOException` instead of the global `Exception`.  By doing this you can potentially have different `catch` blocks for different exceptions, allowing you to treat them differently (perhaps crash with one type, log an error for a different one, show a message to the user for something else, etc.).

Comment: I would go so far to say that the deleteFile method as shown is completely unnecessary.  Just call File.Delete.  The method as written doesn't add any value.

Comment: unnecessary to call deleteFile from the class ?

Comment: @user1710944 There's no need to create a new method called `deleteFile`, just call `File.Delete` directly.  You're not doing anything extra (that you should be doing) so putting it in a new custom method adds nothing.